# SpriteKit - how to use font atlas in spriteKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I am porting my project from cocos2D to spritekit and seems that spritekit has nothing besides SKLabelNode. Does Xcode6 have any tweaks for BMFonts, or BM Fonts are not needed any more?

Comment: glyph designer comes with a bmfont implementation for sprite kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 6 does not have any sort of tool to edit BM Fonts. However, as LearnCocos2D pointed out in the comments below the question, [Glyph Designer](https://71squared.com/glyphdesigner) might be the tool you are looking for. [Here is a link](https://71squared.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200037472-Using-Glyph-Designer-1-8-with-Sprite-Kit) to an example of how to use it with Sprite Kit. It's pretty slick.

Comment: Any cached version of the example link? It's a 404 now